# Prove or disprove: there exists no binary operation $*$ on $\mathbb Q^+$ s.t. $(\mathbb Q^+,*)$ is not isomorphic to $(\mathbb Q^+,×)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, binary-operations

I am a first year college student who just started studying abstract algebra.

I have been discussing the following problem with my friends at another university for a couple of days:

**Prove or disprove: there exists no binary operation $*$ on $\mathbb Q^+$ s.t. $(\mathbb Q^+,*)$ is not isomorphic to $(\mathbb Q^+,×)$**

I have been trying to wrap my head on this problem, but I could not accept the claim that there cannot be any isomorphism at all. For instance, why would not the identity mapping form the isomorphism between the two groups? If not, could you please pinpoint my wrong intuition and guide me on how to approach this problem?

Comment: When talking about isomorphism in this context, you want it to preserve operations, i.e. $f(x*y) = f(x)\times f(y)$ and $f^{-1}(x\times y) = f^{-1}(x)* f^{-1}(y)$. This disqualifies identity if you want $*$ and $\times$ to be different.

Comment: For clarity, you might want to rephrase "...no binary operation $*$ other than the usual multiplication $\times$ s.t...." because other wise $*=\times$ would do the trick :-)

Comment: Also, you meant to say "is isomorphic" or "is not isomorphic"?

Comment: The original problem was worded as “is not isomorphic” but I think changing to “is isomorphic” might remove redundancy!

Comment: @Sampah I think it's safe to assume that they meant what they wrote since the alternative is trivial.

Comment: Rosemary, "is not isomorphic" is not redundant version of "is isomorphic" in this case.

Comment: To clarify, let $S$ be the set of all binary operations $*$ on $\mathbb Q^+$ (probably with certain properties that question doesn't specify, but without some assumptions, the question is trivial) such that $(\mathbb Q^+,*)\cong (\mathbb Q^+,\times)$. The question asks if there exists a binary operation (with certain properties) on $\mathbb Q^+$ not in $S$.

Comment: @Ennar I see, thank you for clarifying my mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f: \mathbb Q^+ \to \mathbb Z$ be a bijection between the integers and the positive rationals.
Define $$x*y = f^{-1}\left( f(x) + f(y)\right).$$
Then $(\mathbb Q^+, *) \approx(\mathbb Z, +)$. But the integers under addition are not isomorphic to the positive rationals under multiplication.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I can finally sleep in peace.